# Ensuring that Oracle sequence does not violate Java Integer constraints

Tags: oracle, java, sequence

Take for example a standard primary key on a JPA entity (POJO), similar to what is described by the first section of [Configuring a JPA Entity Primary Key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm) in the Oracle® Containers for J2EE Enterprise JavaBeans Developer's Guide:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ORGANIZATION_ID_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="ORGANIZATION_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
@Column(name="ORGANIZATION_ID")
private Integer organizationId;
```

Let's assume that the data in this table has the potential to be extremely large (over 2 billion rows). The sequence `ORGANIZATION_ID` above, when inspected in TOAD, has a maxValue of `999999999999999` (which is much bigger than the max value for Java Integer) and Cycle set to "No".

I can change the JPA Entity to be `private Long organizationId`, but I'm worried about the cascading impact on this very complex application. Are there any tricks or settings I should be aware of on the Oracle side that would make these sequences play nicely with Java Integers?

Right now, the expectation is that the DBA will simply backup and truncate the tables, then reset the sequences, when they are near Java Integer `MAX_SIZE`.

Comment: Why do you need to backup and truncate the tables for that? Why not just simply `alter sequence ORGANIZATION_ID_SEQ maxvalue 2147483647;` and keep everything?

Comment: If you're concerned, wouldn't it make sense to modify the sequence to have a `max_value` that matches the Java Integer?  That being said, it seems unlikely that you'd have 2 billion different organizations so this doesn't seem like a particularly pressing concern.  If you thought you would have more than 2 billion organizations, the idea that you're going to truncate the table once you got the next organization seems rather suspect.  Re-using keys like that seldom works transparently.

Comment: @BalazsPapp Would I need to turn on Cycle as well? What happens when that max value is reached? We're also seeing problems where the sequence itself seems to not go in order as data is inserted (depending on whether or not the app did so, or a manual SQL query from a DBA, seems to differ in values and skip over many)

Comment: Not necessarily, but you will receive an `ORA-08004` when the maxvalue is reached and `NOCYCLE` is used. The skipped values are most likely caused by the caching of the sequence values and using the default `NOORDER` option. You can guarantee that the sequence values are generated in order with the `ORDER` option (which we usually do not want). This will still not prevent the values out of order entered manually, for that, a trigger could be used.

Comment: You practically never do any math with database IDs. So avoid using Int or Long for them. For Oracle database IDs is natural choice BigDecimal datatype. IHMO it even should be faster, because they both use the same internal format(BCD)

Comment: @BalazsPapp or anyone else: Another followup: If we already have large sets of data in the DB with huge gaps in their primary key IDs, does CYCLE fill in those gaps when it resets back to 0? What is best practice for filling in gaps on primary keys?

Comment: Best practice of filling in gaps (as much as possible) is to use ORDER NOCACHE. But you still run the risk of missing if you insert and then rollback. I am not a java expert but what @ibre5041 says makes sense. You want to update your java app to accommodate large values not the other way if possible. Now sometimes it is required to use smaller max value because you need to start from 1 on a daily basis (trading companies etc do this sometimes). Then you set a smaller max value, else you don't have to unless there are other business constraints or pre-packaged vendor app limitation.

Comment: Furthermore does your business logic *requires* lossless sequences or as a developer you want it while business will be fine either way? That is the big question. If you want truly lossless, you have to manage it yourself (i.e. not using sequences) because you need to cater for rollbacks. Such solutions are generally (speaking) not very scalable.